# How to get a URL in PHP

Tags: php

I have a photo gallery and have to have the photos' URLs in their bottons. How can I do that in PHP?

The location of file is in 'http://localhost/jordan pagaduan/user_images...'

Comment: What on earth are you asking?

Comment: Check out the `$_SERVER` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) variables, what you're looking for is probably there.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` may be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $['REQUEST_URI']` maybe this?